# An equivalent for the Bernoulli equation for viscous liquids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity, bernoulli-equation

I was wondering whether there is any equation for viscous liquids (probably derived from energy and mass conservation principles) relating the pressure, rate of volume flow, area of cross section and  height of the liquid (or any other parameters if required).

NOTE : I am aware of [Poiseuille's law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ppois.html), but that is not what I am looking for as it relates the pressure *gradient* to the rate of flow.

Comment: have you tried searching for "Bernoulli's Equation for viscous fluids" on google? I tried it just now and probably 60-78.3% of the hits are pretty much what you're looking for

Comment: For pipe-design purposes, usually as pressure losses per length of pipe is added into bernoulli, and the corners and inlets/outlets are also counted as energy losses. There's books out there with tables for these. A quick google look-up pop this up: http://www.nzifst.org.nz/unitoperations/flfltheory5.htm

Comment: But to answer your question, if you start with Navier Stokes you get all the viscosity there. Start taking down the stuff you don't need, and you'll have yourself an equation.

Comment: See Introductory Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, Lightfoot and
Klingenberg: Example 3.3-1 for inviscid fluids; Sections 7.4 & 7.7 for the complete derivation for viscous fluids. The latter is sometimes
referred to as the "engineers' Bernoulli equation."

Answer (score 1):

I think Euler-Bernoulli equation is nothing but the energy equation of a steady-state inviscid flow in Lagrangian form. It means the total non-thermal energy of an imaginary particle doesn't change alongside the stream:

$$P+\rho \frac{v^2}{2}=cte \tag{1}$$

Assuming that body force is negligible. So if you want to extend it to vicious flows you have two possibilities. Of course the obvious way is to use conservative continuum equations for mass, linear momentum and energy for the 3D flow (i.e. Navier-Stokes equations). But if your flow can be reduced to a 1D model, Like a pipe or an orifice, then we can write:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \bar{P}+ \bar{\rho}\frac{\bar{v}^2}{2}\right)={loss}_x \tag{2a}$$

as the loss of energy at each section of the pipe. If assuming conduction and radiation are negligible (adiabatic) then:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \bar{h}+ \frac{\bar{v}^2}{2}\right)=0 \tag{2b}$$

Now the [Darcy-Weisbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation)  formula can be used to have an estimation of the loss:

$${loss}_x \approx -f \frac{ \bar{\rho} \bar{v}^2}{2 D_H} \tag{3}$$

Where $D_H$ is the [hydraulic diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_diameter) at that particular section and $f$ is the [Darcy friction factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae). There are actually a whole bunch of empirical equations for $f$ for different flow regimes. [Hagen–Poiseuille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) equation is the most primitive one for laminar flow. I have explained more [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/352412/113880). Anyway combining 2 and 3 :

$$\implies \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \bar{P}+ \bar{\rho}\frac{\bar{v}^2}{2}\right) \approx -f \frac{ \bar{\rho} \bar{v}^2}{2 D_H} \tag{4}$$

Which I think should be a good estimation for the a 1D viscous flow.